# How do I get the Tweet/social buttons to appear on an answer I posted?

Tags: support

I've noticed on occasion after posting an answer I get the "Share your Answer!" bar with Facebook/twitter icons. Does this bar only show up when I first post an answer? I can't seem to find those options deliberately, and other some SE sites don't even seem to *have* them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This only appears:

- a random percent of the time, decreasing chance with greater reputation
- on your posts
- if they are greater than 400 characters in length
- for 1 hour after posting

[Please ditch all of the share icons - they give me nightmares](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80880/please-ditch-all-of-the-share-icons-they-give-me-nightmares/80910#80910)